# svn does not work anymore

Tags: cygwin

All of the sudden svn stopped working in cygwin installation on windows xp.  when I execute svn binary, nothing happens, svn process does not even show up in the Task Manager. I've  reinstalled svn but it did not help (the last resort would be to uninstall cygwin itself). Everything else in cygwin works fine: awk,python,sed,more,less,tail and etc.

here is what is happening ...

```
mt@s022 ~
$ which svn
/usr/bin/svn

mt@s022 ~
$ svn --version

mt@s022 ~
$ svn status

mt@s022 ~
$ svn info

mt@s022 ~
$
```

Comment: what does ls -l /usr/bin/svn give ? (just to check the size and potential symlink ? )

Comment: -rwxr-x---+ 1 mt Users 159744 Jul  9 13:43 /usr/bin/svn

Comment: Has the svn binary been overwritten somehow...?  Try "cat svn".

Comment: I finally gave up (it was taking too much time) .... replaced cygwin's svn binaries with tigris.  But I tried to reinstall  and downgrade SVN  without much help.

Comment: What version of Cygwin are you using? SVN 1.6.9 with Cygwin 1.7.1 works fine for me.

Comment: it was 1.6.3. since I could not find a solution I removed svn  from cygwin and install windows version (collabnet). Now I have to watch for "slash".

Answer (score 3):

Same problem as well.

No solution, but here's an interesting thing:  For me, "curl" and "wget" are also broken in exactly the same way.  This makes me wonder if it is one of the underlying networking libraries (libcurl, or similar) that is at the root of the problem (total guess).

EDIT:   I have solved this problem.   The problem turned out to be what seems to have been a "bad" version of openssl.  I used the Cygwin setup program to "Reinstall" OpenSSL.  The version number in setup is now "0.9.8n" which seems to have replaced "0.9.8", which I suspect was a bad version that was temporarily distributed, so if you were unlucky enough to update at the wrong time then this is what you got.  The new version doesn't seem to be installed automatically just by updating normally.  I'm guessing 0.9.8 is seen as the same version as 0.9.8n.

In case this doesn't solve it for others:  the key insight was gained by launching svn.exe from Windows Explorer.  While it exits silently when run from the bash command line, when run from Windows Explorer it pops up a window complaining:  "the procedure entry point pqueue_size could not be located in the dynamic link library cygcrypto-0.9.8.dll".  This allowed me to identify OpenSSL as the culprit.  The same might be possible for other problems that manifest as commands silently exiting when run from the bash terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

1. net stop sshd (this is optional)
2. remove /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
3. remove /usr/bin/cygcrypto-0.9.8.dll
4. run cygwin-setup
5. reinstall cygwin-base

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem. It seemed to have started when I added one small package and left everything else as `keep`. Solution that worked: remove `cygwin1.dll`, run cygwin's `setup.exe`, `keep` everything except `base->cygwin`. Updating that updated `cygwin1.dll`, and all was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
I followed the suggestion above and tried to launch svn from the windows explorer and it turned out that I had a problem with cygwin1.dll itself.

Doing a reinstall of the cygwin package solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and upgrading/reinstalling the cygwin base classes didn't help me neither...

Until I disabled the "CYGWIN sshd" service.

Therefore, if you run the Cygwin sshd process, stop it first, before upgrading Cygwin.

Good luck!